Permission Denial Exception in Content Provider on Specific Devices Only When Installed via Play Store
I have a content provider that is shared across multiple Android apps, allowing them to access specific user data. Each app has the necessary permissions to access the other apps' content providers, and everything works well in local tests and on the Google Play Store. However, I'm encountering an issue on certain devices where one app is unable to connect to the other apps' content providers.
Details:
The issue occurs on specific devices (e.g., Galaxy S22 Ultra, Galaxy A70).
The problem does not occur when installing the app directly via Unity, where the system functions as intended.
Upon checking the logs, the following error is observed:
Error checking content provider availability for URI content://de.testcompany.android.testappone.subscriptionprovider: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider de.testcompany.subscriptioncontentprovider.SubscriptionContentProvider from ProcessRecord{552b32 12726:com.testcompany.de.testapptwo/u0a465} (pid=12726, uid=10465) requires com.unity3d.player.testappone.ACCESS_DATA or com.unity3d.player.testappone.ACCESS_DATA
I verified the Android manifest in the .aab file using Android Studio, and the required permission (com.unity3d.player.testappone.ACCESS_DATA) is indeed present.
This issue can be replicated on a Galaxy S22 Ultra and a Galaxy A70, but not on a Galaxy A12, for example. Many other devices also work without issues.
Question:
Why might this problem occur on specific devices and only when the app is installed via the Play Store, but not when installed directly via Unity? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
